# Why I'm getting TLE even if I'm using memoization?

Tags: c++, recursion, memoization, cp

Here is the question statement

Given two strings s1 and s2, return the length of their longest common subsequence.

A subsequence of a string is a new string generated from the original string with some characters(can be none) deleted without changing the relative order of the remaining characters. (eg, "ace" is a subsequence of "abcde" while "aec" is not). A common subsequence of two strings is a subsequence that is common to both strings.

If there is no common subsequence, return 0.

Here is my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    int dp[1001][1001];
    int lcs(string s1,string s2,int n,int m){
        if (n==0 || m == 0)
            return 0;
        if(dp[n][m]!=-1)
            return dp[n][m];
        if (s1[n-1] == s2[m-1])
        {
            return dp[n][m]=  1 + lcs(s1,s2,n-1,m-1);
        }
        else
        {
            return dp[n][m]= max(lcs(s1,s2,n-1,m), lcs(s1,s2,n,m-1));
        }
        return dp[n][m];
    }
    int longestCommonSubsequence(string s1, string s2) {
        memset(dp,-1,1001*1001*sizeof(int));
        return lcs(s1,s2, s1.size(), s2.size());
        
    }
};
```

Thank You

Comment: Do you need to pass by value all the strings?

Comment: @Nishant Sagar always use `memset(dp, -1, sizeof (dp))`  because you may change size of` dp` or datatype of `dp` it may give an unexpected result.

Comment: BTW, are you sure this is the correct algorithm? When passed `"abcde"` and `"ba"`, the function returns 2. Shouldn't it be 1, by the question statement?

Comment: I supposed by TLE you mean Time Limit Exceeded, but the world does not proft infinitely from an endless proliferation of TLAs.

Comment: `return dp[n][m];` will never execute at end of `lcs` function.

Comment: @Bob__ its not the longest common substring, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use call by reference in function definition instead of call by value.

```cpp
int lcs(string &s1,string &s2,int n,int m);
```

```cpp
int longestCommonSubsequence(string &s1, string &s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation has at least 2 further improvements that can be made.

- You are using a recursive algorithm, rewrite it to an iterative version
- You are using a 1001*1001 array and therefor you are trashing the cache to some extend

There exists a much more space efficient algorithm, [Hirschberg's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg%27s_algorithm), for just returning the length of the LCS.